# (click) event not working in HTML template

Tags: angular

The `(click)` event is not working in my component.

HTML:

```html
<button (click)="onClick">Click</button>
```

Below is the method in my component class.

```ts
onClick(): void { console.log('Button Clicked'); }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onClick` should be a function

Try this

```
<button (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
```

Here is the working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oudvby?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have added the function body in the question. That is defined in my component class.

Comment: @Jith try that link

Comment: any thing I need to import in my component class to make it work?

Comment: no you don't just check the example I have provided. you just need to replace `onClick`  with `onClick()`.

Comment: Which isn't a function :)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<button (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
```

or

```
<button on-click="onClick()">Click</button>
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgccbj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have same button declaration in my template file.